# Capistrano deployment aborted because of Composer

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, composer-php, capistrano

I've an issue with my cap deployment when the command runs :

> /usr/bin/env composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction --no-progress --optimize-autoloader

It takes few minutes before I receive this error message:

> composer stdout: Warning: proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 954
>
> composer stderr: Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> The following exception is caused by a lack of memory and not having swap configured
>
> Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details

If i'm going to the current release of project on the server, and I remove vendor folder, then I execute "composer install", it works.

Locally, on my computer, mamp env, I execute this command with a memory limit :

> php -dmemory_limit=2G /usr/local/bin/composer install

it works also.

The problem occurs only when I use capistrano deployment.

Any idea ?

For information :

1. I checked the server, it has 4Go Ram.
2. Swap is activated.
3. php memory limit is set -1.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: which version of php are you using? Is composer.lock part of your repo?

Comment: @KasiaGogolek 5.5.9 , yes there is a composer.lock file

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my config with 6Go RAM. Composer install seems working ... but why does it need so much memory ?